Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.navigate()" because the return value of "DI_constructor.pagecontext.getDriver()" is null
I have a DI constructor for myhooks, I think it's set up properly but I'm getting an error regardless:
Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.navigate()" because the return value of "DI_constructor.pagecontext.getDriver()" is null

I'm also using Cucumber JUnit, but I'm not sure why my hooks are not triggering, even with my test runner classes.
This is my DI class:
package DI_constructor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class pagecontext {
    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public void setDriver(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    private WebDriver driver;
}

This is my hooks class:
package Hooks;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;

public class myhooks {
    private pagecontext context;
    
    public myhooks(pagecontext context) {
        this.context=context; 
    }
    
    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","C:/Users/DINESH.PALANIYANDI/eclipse-workspace/Shopify/src/test/resources/Drivers/msedgedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new EdgeDriver();
        context.setDriver(driver);
        context.getDriver().manage().window().maximize();
        context.getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
    }
    
    @AfterClass
    public void teardown() {
        context.getDriver().close();
        context.getDriver().quit();
    }
}

This is my first test runner class "ts01":
package Testrunner;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        
        features = {"src/test/resources/Features/F01_RegisterwithShopify.feature"},
        plugin = {"pretty","html:C:/Users/DINESH.PALANIYANDI/eclipse-workspace/Shopify/target/Reports/F01_RegisterwithShopify.html"},
        glue = {"StepDefinations_TS"}, 
        monochrome = true, 
        dryRun = false  )

public class TestrunnerTS01 {

}

This is my 2nd test runner class "ts02":
package Testrunner;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        
        features = {"src/test/resources/Features/F02_Configureyourstore.feature"},
        glue = {"StepDefinations_TS"}, 
        plugin = {"pretty","html:C:/Users/DINESH.PALANIYANDI/eclipse-workspace/Shopify/target/Reports/F02_Configureyourstore.html"},
        monochrome = true, 
        dryRun = false  )

public class TestRunnerTS02 {

}


Created the page context constructor  in my step defination c;lasses... where the issue.. not showing any error in code.. i initialized properly... any can connect over the call and guid me-8920304910(This is my whats app number also)... I am doing all these effor from scratch BDD and am not getting oppertunity in automation.. right now, need to get the clarity on this .. if anyone helped/connect , would be grateful...

though it's not the cause of this error, you should remove this line:  context.getDriver().close();  (That would quit/dispose of driver if it's the only tab/window open in the browser.)  Where is driver.navigate() or driver.get() method called?  Where is new page context created?  I'd put in a constructor there and make sure to initialize the driver when it's created.  Just easier to deal with that way as is, it's treated as a static class that might have many instances.

having said that I'm not familiar with cucumber/bdd so make sure to follow the framework's way of doing things.

In cucumber, step definition class, context.getdriver().get() used. but, still facing error like can not invoke driver.. page context - i have called each class as well and passing the driver instance. For parellel execution interms of BDD, using static is not best practice.  that why ,goes to DI constructor pico container...

Many expert's are  here.. no one helping on the same to rectify the issue

the way it's currently designed can confuse what "context" is.  The step definitions would need to pass in myhooks, as that's probably got a single instance.  so myhooks.context.getdriver... but not familiar with this framework.  It doesn't seem like context in myhooks should be private, but not sure how the steps get the injected context.

This will crystal clear defined DI constructor. Issue got resolved. Context is the instance of DI class and from that class, am calling the driver instance and passing to the multiple step defination classes that context.gerdriver() instead of driver. Issue got resolved because I didn't mention the hooks package in test runner (glue). Each steps defination class using constructor and calling the resused steps there.. I can pass all those objects in DI class also... I mentioned all related and specific to the class and only passing the the driver instance from here .if you used the  framework

Thanks ji for the suggestions and help against your inputs on this issue.  Issue was in test runner file.. I didn't mention this hooks anywhere in the runner file.. after that, it is exciting fine... For Parellel execution, static and inheriting by the class using extens(this will be straightforward and simplicity for smaller projects . But larger projects you will face some complications)are not best approach.. DI constructor using without using static good .

Bro, I will share the framework structure when have time- am using Java -Cucumber-Junit for test report...
